# What is the following sequence and what is the method to solve it?

Tags: math, sequence

In which step of the sequence below is the number 4 placed?

[image: Sequence]

Comment: I don't know, but a resource you can explore is the Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (http://oeis.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is called "look-and-say sequence", and according to one of its properties "Digits presence limitation", no digits other than 1, 2 and 3 will appear in the sequence, therefore, it will be no step will be placed by number 4.

Comment: It's not quite the look-and-say sequence, though. If it were, the 5th line would be `1,1,1,2,2,1` (rather than `1,1,2,2,1`), and the 6th line would be `3,1,2,2,1,1` rather than `3,1,2,2,1`. I'm _guessing_ that those are just typos by whoever set the question, but still ... (ref: https://oeis.org/A005150)